# How can I hide an HTML table row <tr> so that it takes up no space?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How can I hide an HTML table row `<tr>` so that it takes up no space?  I have several `<tr>`'s set to `style="display:none;"`, but they still affect the size of the table and the table's border reflects the hidden rows.

Comment: Are they being repeatedly shown/hidden? Or when they're hidden, are they effectively gone for good?  Because you could use javascript to just remove the row and it would probably fix your issue.

Comment: I want to start them off as hidden, and then show them if the user clicks on a button to "show more".  When they are hidden, I don't want them to take up vertical space.

Comment: i had this same issue, if you remove() the row with javascript, it still takes up some space in IE6. no way around sucky IE

Comment: What doctype are you using? I accept that the simple fact that you're posting on SO with a good rep indicates that you probably know enough to avoid quirks mode...but the only stupid question is one that's not asked. ...and the one about the budgerigars, obviously.

Comment: I just tested in FF 3.5 and IE8 - both hide the row with display:none

Comment: refer [this link][1] for easy show hide


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32474501/3583859

Comment: I was having a lot of trouble with this until I realized that to get it _back_ properly, I had to use `style="display:table-row"`. Without that, it was hiding but the next row tried to fit itself into the first cell. Or some weird thing like that.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I would really like to see your TABLE's styling. E.g. "border-collapse"

Just a guess, but it might affect how 'hidden' rows are being rendered.

Answer (score 128):

Can you include some code? I add `style="display:none;"` to my table rows all the time and it effectively hides the entire row.

Comment: worked for me. I was trying to set visibility: hidden before :(

Comment: There is still spacing :/

Comment: how to prevent this from changing the width of the table when you show hide rows, i dont want to do table layout fixed

Comment: I had forgotten about the style... I simply had display="none;"  and was mind boggled as to why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 75):

You can set `<tr id="result_tr" style="display: none;">` and then show it back with JavaScript:

```
var result_style = document.getElementById('result_tr').style;
result_style.display = 'table-row';
```

Comment: Thank-you!! Hiding was easy, but brining them back was proving problematic.

Comment: this changes the width of the table , i am doing a filter where rows need to be shown hidden based on whats inside the searchbox

Answer (score 44):

Thought I'd add to this a potential other solution:

`<tr style='visibility:collapse'><td>stuff</td></tr>`

I've only tested it on Chrome but putting this on the `<tr>` hides the row PLUS all the cells inside the row still contribute to the widths of the columns.  I will sometimes make an extra row at the bottom of a table with just some spacers that make it so certain columns can't be less than a certain width, then hide the row using this method.  (I know you're supposed to be able to do this with other css but I've never gotten that to work)

Again, I'm in a purely chrome environment so I have no idea how this functions in other browsers.

Comment: This works in most modern browsers, with the notable exception of Safari, which renders whitespace rather than hiding the row: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: This worked perfectly. It maintained the column widths while hiding the row. The display: none solution changes the columns sizes which results in a jarring experience. Thanks!

Comment: joined late here but it was worth saying it helped me to effectively hide some given rows including the very first one without affecting the table layout ruled by the rowspan attribute on top. Layout that was screwed up if I used display:none.

Comment: This is the only solution I can find that hides a row without changing the column widths. I should add that I have nested / indented rows that can be collapsed (hidden).

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I had been trying to build a table and I like to keep width styling information for columns of unique tables in `thead` for readability. But the table I was working on had no semantic reason for a top header row. Styling of the hidden row isn't ignored with this like it is with `display: none;`.

Answer (score 9):

If `display: none;` doesn't work, how about setting `height: 0;` instead? In conjunction with a negative margin (equal to, or greater than, the height of the top and bottom borders, if any) to further remove the element? I don't imagine that `position: absolute; top: 0; left: -4000px;` would work, but it might be worth a try.

For my part, using `display: none` works fine.

Comment: I had thought of this. However to use `height` on a `tr` element you still need to change the `display` type from the default to something like `block`.

Answer (score 4):

Add some of the following line-height:0px;font-size:0px;height:0px;margin:0;padding:0;

I forget which one does it.  I think it's line-height for IE6.

Answer (score 4):

You can use style display:none with tr to hide and it will work with all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

```
var result_style = document.getElementById('result_tr').style;
result_style.display = '';
```

is working perfectly for me..

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue, I even added style="display: none" to each cell.

In the end I used HTML comments 
    `<!-- [HTML] -->`

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me and I was baffled as to why.  Then I noticed that if i removed any nbsp; i had within the rows, then the rows didn't take up any space.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem; I'm making a leaderboard thing that can display different difficulty highscores by pressing buttons.

But after screwing around for the better part of 2 hours, I found out some stuffs:

You can use this code to hide with a button press (JavaScript):

`document.getElementById('mytr').style='display:none;';`

Show with a button press:

`document.getElementById('mytr').style='display:table-row;';`

Start off hidden (To later bring back with button press):

`<tr id='mytr'style='display:none;'>`

Hope this helped!

P.S.
You can also show & hide headers  in a similar way, only to show the header instead of writing `'display:table-row;'` you write `'display:table-header;'`.
This can **also** be used to change row into headers & headers into rows.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the change the input type to hidden, all the functions of it work but it is not visible on the page

```
<input type="hidden" name="" id="" value="">
```

as long as the input type is set to that you can change the rest.
Good Luck!!

Answer (score -3):

I was having same problem and I resolved the issue.
Earlier css was overflow:hidden; z-index:999999;

I change it to overflow:visible;

Answer (score -4):

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="attraction" checked="checked" onchange="updateMap()">poi.attraction</input>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updateMap() {
     map.setOptions({'styles': getStyles() });
} 

function getStyles() {
    var styles = [];
    for (var i=0; i < types.length; i++) {
      var style = {};
      var type = types[i];
      var enabled = document.getElementById(type).checked;
      style['featureType'] = 'poi.' + type;
      style['elementType'] = 'labels';
      style['stylers'] = [{'visibility' : (enabled ? 'on' : 'off') }];
      styles.push(style);
    }
    return styles;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

`position: absolute` will remove it from the layout flow and should solve your problem - the element will remain in the DOM but won't affect others.

Comment: fwiw I think this is a great solution if you want to hide a column, in some specific situations. in addition add `opacity: 0`

Answer (score -6):

You can set

```
<table>
  <tr style="visibility: hidden"></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: With `visibility: hidden;` the element will still take space, that's the difference between `visibility` and `display` properties

Comment: Use like this `<table><tr style="display: none;"><td></td></tr></table>`