# Hide Table Row Using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Is it possible to hide table rows using CSS, I have a project that required this concept.
Here is my code:

**style.css:**

```
#hide-row { display:none; }
```

**file.php**

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
  <div id="hide-row">
     <?php foreach( $cops as $row ) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php } ?>
  </div>
</table>
```

But, It didn't work, the records still appear. Anybody help how to solve this case?
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You in Advanced !

Comment: do you have multiple `hide-row` ids?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a class instead of an id:

```
.hide-row { display:none; }
```

And in your html/php file:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
     <?php foreach( $cops as $row ) { ?>
        <tr class="hide-row">
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php } ?>
</table>
```

If you have to group your rows you could use a `tbody` tag instead of a `div` tag.

[Can we have multiple <tbody> in same <table>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076708/can-we-have-multiple-tbody-in-same-table)

```
 .hide-row tr { display:none; }
```

And in your html/php file:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
  </tr>
    <tbody class="hide-row">
     <?php foreach( $cops as $row ) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
        </tr>
     <?php } ?>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you Jantimon, it works perfectly. I choose the 2nd option. Actually I want to display it in smooth toggle via Jquery when the user click something that related to the iterations. -)

Comment: This is accepted answer but better solution is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144123/how-can-i-hide-an-html-table-row-tr-so-that-it-takes-up-no-space
and the reason is that page position ( scrolling ) is different. With `display:none` is incorrect when table is big and hide/show button is under table. With `visibility:collapse` cursor is where it should be after rows are hidden.

Answer (score 3):

You can't put divs as direct children of a < table> element. To hide single rows see jantimon's answer. If you want to group multiple rows use < tbody>:

css

```
.hide-row { display:none; }
```

php

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody class="hide-row">
        <?php foreach( $cops as $row ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: +1 for no div child of a `table` (or `tbody` or `thead` or `tfoot`). Descendant, yes, if there `tr` in-between (I edited your answer to reflect the fact that you can have divs in a table, but in `tr>td` or `tr>th`)

Answer (score 2):

You can't nest a `div` inside a `table` tag directly. You'd have to give your rows a class, then hide that. Something like:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}

<?php foreach( $cops as $row ) { ?>
    <tr class="hidden">
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
    </tr>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot have `<div>` outside `<tr>`.. give the class to `<tr>` and hide that..no need to create a `<div>` around it

**html**

```
<tr class="hide-row">
        <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

**style.css**

```
.hide-row { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would give each row you want hidden  a `hide-row` class:

```
<tr class="hide-row">
```

Your CSS would then look like:

```
tr.hide-row { display: none; }
```

This then means you don't need the nested div.