# Why does setting display to none in the code-behind not add it to the HTML?

Tags: c#, html, css, html-table, htmltable-control

I'm trying to set the display style of a couple of HtmlTableRows to "display:none" in code-behind like so:

```
foapalrow3 = new HtmlTableRow();
foapalrow3.ID = "foapalrow3";
foapalrow3.Attributes["display"] = "none";
```

...but it's not working - the "View Source" contains no "display:none" for either foapalrow3 or -4. Why not, and how can I force this to work as intended?

Either my nogging or the wall is going to eventually crumble with this; I've been slamming like a fullback into a brick wall with it, as this [stream-of-codedness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31091241/how-can-i-show-a-formerly-hidden-htmltablerow-via-jquery) shows.

Comment: The output will contain the *HTML attribute* 'display' - ie. `<tr display="none"..>` - which has naught to do with CSS.

Comment: Actually, the rows are not decorated with anything; in fact, they're not even in the HTML (the hidden ones are not).

Comment: Setting `Visible = false` *disables* control rendering server-side. *If* the control *was* rendered it *would* have the attribute. Rendering-to-HTML, or not, is independent of the Attribute collection and hence the code shown; switching to use the Style collection or style attribute will not change this.

Comment: Yeah, I just commented out the visible jazz and it's working pretty sweetly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display` is not an HTML attribute, so it is discarded. If you want to add CSS styles, use `Style` instead of `Attributes` like this:

```
foapalrow3.Style["display"] = "none";
foapalrow4.Style.Add("display", "none"); // alternate syntax
```

As the other answer states, you could theoretically accomplish the same thing with `Attributes["style"]`, but personally I've had issues with that in the past and the `Style` property is the preferred (and in my opinion, superior) option.

Answer (score 2):

`display` is not the name of the attribute. You have to modify the `style` attribute.

```
foapalrow3.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";
```

Comment: Thanks; I reckon your way is probably right, too, but I marked the answer correct for the cat with fewer points (I always favor the underdog - unless the underdog is a jerk, that is).